# jdk17u161 plugin.jar size is 1 kb

Tags: java

Experts,

I have installed JDK 17u161 b31 release in my local. facing build failure issues with following missing folder under plugin.jar.  As i checked the plugin.jar size is 1KB which is not expected comparing previous release JDK 17u151. Please advise me the possibilities to resolve the issues.

**AppletContextStub.java:16: error: package sun.plugin.javascript does not exist
[ERROR] import sun.plugin.javascript.JSContext;**

Thanks,
Anitha.S

Comment: There is too much information missing. What's your OS? From which URL did you obtain the copy of JDK 17u161 b31 from? Did you compare checksums? What installation package did you choose if there were multiple to choose from? Have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: silly quesiton, can u try another release? why not java 8 ?

Comment: OS i use windows 2012R2, Downloaded from bellow oracle site.  https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1439822.1&_adf.ctrl-state=g5h46fm79_4&_afrLoop=447976453922520

Comment: From where did you install JRE17u161? It is not public right?

Comment: viking , my project recommended java 7

Comment: its not a public i have installed on my windows 2012  R2 server. JDK downloaded from oracle site i have posted above.

Answer (score 0):

Login to support.oracle.com for details. Search for [DocID 1640397.1](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=539204941765338&id=1640397.1&_adf.ctrl-state=18k5u8sypc_114)

Starting with the October 2017 CPU release, the Deployment stack is removed from all Java SE 6 and Java SE 7 platform releases.

- Deployment stack code fixes are now released for JRE 8+ only1 ('JRE 8+' means JRE 8 or later version).
- Deployment issues found with JRE 7 or JRE 6 must be reproduced with a JRE 8+ version.

I suppose the workaround is move to JDK8+ and use -source and -target = 1.6 or 1.7 as appropriate.

The following classes have all been removed:

```
netscape.javascript.
netscape.security
com.sun.java.browser.plugin2
sun.plugin.cache
sun.plugin.dom
sun.plugin.extension
sun.plugin.javascript
sun.plugin.liveconnect
sun.plugin.navig
sun.plugin.net
sun.plugin.perf
sun.plugin.security
sun.plugin.services
sun.plugin.util
sun.plugin.viewersun.plugin2.applet
sun.plugin2.gluegen
sun.plugin2.ipc
sun.plugin2.jvm
sun.plugin2.liveconnect
sun.plugin2.main
sun.plugin2.message
sun.plugin2.os
sun.plugin2.util
```